# Need to give a product free when using a specific coupon

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules

I would like the user get a product free in a particular category (eg 8) free when user enters a specific single used coupon. The user just needs to buy at least one product(any category) to get the free product. Can this be done using shopping cart rule or do I need customization?

Comment: Just apply a 100% discount to a specific SKU in the actions

Comment: Do you need to add the product to the users cart as well? Don't forget to set limits to avoid giving away all your stock!

Comment: If the free product should be added to the cart automatically it cannot be done without customization. But there is a free extension that adds this option to the shopping cart rules: https://github.com/code4business/freeproduct

Comment: In this case the user chooses the product from the category page and when he adds it to the cart the product should be free. I have tried the 100% discount option in Actions and set the "Maximum Qty Discount" is applied to as 1 and in conditions "total items quantity in cart" to greater than 1, but for some reason the discount is being applied to all products in the cart

Comment: I had to use a paid extension to get this working, used the following extension  https://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html  screenshots => https://gyazo.com/6a1625e337f06d6538cf6a650e449ab2 https://gyazo.com/38e426c6dba0d1ea52068648116e6b86

Answer (score 0):

I hope below link help you:

http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-free-gift-product-coupon-code.html

http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/shopping-cart-price-rules-in-magento-walk-through/

demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/10-real-world-examples-of-shopping-cart-price-rules/

Comment: The linked paid extension looks suspiciously similar to this free one: https://github.com/code4business/freeproduct

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply 100% discount coupon, you can create coupon from admin.

```
Admin Dashboard -> promotions -> shopping cart price rules
```